# AngularJS links not working

Tags: angularjs

So, I have decided check out AngularJS, and am working through the Angular Rails tutorial on [thinkster.io](https://thinkster.io/tutorials/angular-rails). I've gotten to the part where you create a second page, and create a link on the home page to get to that page. However, the links do not seem to be working. Here's the html and js files for my progress on the thinkster project:

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flapper News</title>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <style> .glyphicon-thumbs-up {
        cursor: pointer
    } </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="flapperNews">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Flapper News</h1>
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
              ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span>
        {{post.upvotes}}
        <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
            <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
                {{post.title}}
            </a>
            <span ng-hide="post.link">
                {{post.title}}
            </span>
            <span>
                <a href="#/posts/{{$index}}">Comments</a>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>

    <form ng-submit="addPost()"
          style="margin-top:30px;">
        <h3>Add a new post</h3>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text"
                   class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Title"
                   ng-model="title"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text"
                   class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Link"
                   ng-model="link"/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
    </form>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>
            <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
                {{post.title}}
            </a>
            <span ng-hide="post.link">
        {{post.title}}
      </span>
        </h3>
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
          ng-click="incrementUpvotes(comment)"></span>
        {{comment.upvotes}} - by {{comment.author}}
        <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
      {{comment.body}}
    </span>
    </div>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router'])
.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: '/home.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            })
            .state('posts', {
                url: '/posts/{id}',
                templateUrl: '/posts.html',
                controller: 'PostsCtrl'
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
    }
])
.factory('posts', [function() {
    var o = {
        posts: []
    };
    return o;
}])
.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'posts',
    function ($scope, posts) {
        $scope.posts = posts.posts;
        $scope.addPost = function() {
            if (!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') {
                return;
            }
            $scope.posts.push({
                title: $scope.title,
                link: $scope.link,
                upvotes: 0,
                comments: [
                    {author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool post!', upvotes: 0},
                    {author: 'Bob', body: 'Great idea but everything is wrong!', upvotes: 0}
                ]
            });
            $scope.title = '';
            $scope.link = '';
        };
        $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {
            post.upvotes += 1;
        };
    }
])
.controller('PostsCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$stateParams',
    'posts',
    function($scope, $stateParams, posts) {
        $scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];
    }
]);
```

After spending several hours looking at my code, looking at examples online, and looking over the previous steps of the tutorial, I decided to try to create as simple an app as possible to try to get links working in that, also to no avail. Here's the code I wrote for the simpler app:

index2.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flapper News</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="app2.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="flapperNews">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Flapper News</h1>
    </div>
    {{test}}
    <a href="#/posts">Posts</a>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Posts</h1>
    </div>
    {{test}}
    <a href="#/home">Home</a>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

app2.js

```
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router'])
.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: '/home.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            })
            .state('posts', {
                url: '/posts/{id}',
                templateUrl: '/posts.html',
                controller: 'PostsCtrl'
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
    }
])
.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.test = 'Home';
    }
])
.controller('PostsCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.test = 'Posts';
    }
]);
```

Somehow, I think I'm missing something for links that are handled by angular controllers, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what. Any explanation / help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which one you want to fix?

Comment: Ideally both, assuming it's the same issue with both, but the first one is more important.

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: your link to posts doesn't look like it would work because you don't have an id. the url mapping is: /posts/{id} <-- try <a href="/posts/1">Posts</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using the right hashbang prefix, read [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-mode-default-mode-).
This change happened recently and I see that you are using AngularJS ver. `1.6.4`, I don't remember the exact version info but this got changed in 1.6.x or so. So, now all the URL should be prefixed with `'#!'`.

*Suggestion:* Use `ui-sref` in your link rather than `href`. Using `ui-href` you can just provide the name of the state you want to go and `ui-router` will take care of the rest. Also, you can provide params. For more info read about [ui-sref here](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref).

Anyways see the below changed code: 
Also, as @floor mentioned your URL for `posts` is not right as in the state definition you have mentioned `posts/{:id}`, so you have to use `#!/posts/1` or provide a default value in your state definition file.

**Example#1: 'href' version:**

```js
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router'])
  .config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
          url: '/home',
          templateUrl: '/home.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .state('posts', {
          url: '/posts/{id}',
          templateUrl: '/posts.html',
          controller: 'PostsCtrl'
        });

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    }
  ])
  .controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.test = 'Home';
    }
  ])
  .controller('PostsCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.test = 'Posts';
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Flapper News</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="flapperNews">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Flapper News</h1>
    </div>
    {{test}}
    <a href="#!/posts/1">Posts</a>
    <!-- Now the default prefix is '!' -->
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Posts</h1>
    </div>
    {{test}}
    <a href="#!/home">Home</a>
    <!-- Now the default prefix is '!' -->
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Example#2: 'ui-sref' version:**

```js
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router'])
  .config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
          url: '/home',
          templateUrl: '/home.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .state('posts', {
          url: '/posts/{id}',
          templateUrl: '/posts.html',
          controller: 'PostsCtrl'
        });

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    }
  ])
  .controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.test = 'Home';
    }
  ])
  .controller('PostsCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.test = 'Posts';
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Flapper News</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="flapperNews">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Flapper News</h1>
    </div>
    {{test}}
    <a ui-sref="posts">Posts</a>
    <!-- Using ui-sref  -->
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Posts</h1>
    </div>
    {{test}}
    <a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
    <!-- Using ui-sref -->
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems to be in your route defined by you.
If you want to navigate posts state then you should also pass some id as url parameter since you have defined the route in this way.

So please change your app2.js file to code shown below:

```
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router'])
.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: '/home.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            })
            .state('posts', {
                url: '/posts', // id is removed from the request parameter.
                templateUrl: '/posts.html',
                controller: 'PostsCtrl'
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
    }
])
.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.test = 'Home1';
    }
])
.controller('PostsCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.test = 'Posts';
    }
]);
```

> Or if you want id to be in your request parameter then you can do it
>   in this way

```
 <a href="#/posts/1">Posts</a>
```

I think this post will solve your problem. Thanks